# Unable to enter variable to SliverAppBar title value

Tags: flutter

I have an application. I've added a page to my app and that page will have product information. I was also able to redirect to the page and show the information on that page. I want to put the name of the product in the title value of the `SliverAppBar`. The product name is written in the `productName` variable.

But I can't enter a variable in the `SliverAppBar`'s `title` value. When trying to login I get this error:

[image]

```
Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.dart(const_eval_throws_exception)

A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'String' in a const constructor.
Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'.dartconst_constructor_param_type_mismatch

Avoid using braces in interpolation when not needed.dartunnecessary_brace_in_string_interps

Invalid constant value.
```

---

Codes:

```
child: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    const SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      expandedHeight: 250.0,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Text("Product ${productName}"),
      ),
    ),
  // ...
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `const` keyword in front of  `SliverAppBar` widget

```
 SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      expandedHeight: 250.0,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Text("Product ${productName}"),
      ),
    ),
```